# How to upload postgreSql backup to S3 aws

Tags: asp.net-mvc, postgresql, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I'm creating a job which is run daily and upload a PostgreSQL backup to S3 aws.
but I don't know how can do that thing.
for this, I'm doing so many googling but don't find any solution.

please suggest me.

Comment: Which kind of backup? Are you trying it through AWS data pipeline or you are creating some job in say jenkins and exporting postgres data to a dump and then uploading to s3?

Comment: @deosha: creating my job in Nodejs code. like scheduler, I want to run my scheduler which is dump poStgreSql data to s3

Comment: So can you put here the part of code which is trying to upload the dump over s3? Also, can you attach here the policy attached to s3? What is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/backup.html

> There are three fundamentally different approaches to backing up
>   PostgreSQL data:
>
> SQL dump
>
> File system level backup
>
> Continuous archiving

None of three has any native js interface - only OS commands. Even second approach requires first stopping instance (which can be done with OS level commands only)...

S3 part has https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html